# Direct Sum Uniqueness - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove: If $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ satisfying $U_1 \bigoplus W = U_2 \bigoplus W$, then $U_1=U_2$.

My first thought is that this statement is true. Since $U_1 \bigoplus W = U_2 \bigoplus W$, then $U_1+W=U_2+W$ which means $U_1=U_2$. Is that all I need to do?

Comment: Hint: No, it is not true. You can find a counter example by looking at a $2$-dimensional vector space with suitably chosen $1$-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Why do you think thing you can cancel like that? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, say, and any three distinct one-dimensional subspaces $U_1, U_2, W$.